# Xcode hot key for 'tab'

Tags: xcode

I want to ask a stupid question. Can Xcode like be the Visual studio, when I highlight the word and press the 'tab' key, the highlighted word will go to the right side and have a 'tab' space, but I am not able to do this in Xcode, do I need to set something? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xcode, use <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> to increase indent, and <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> to decrease indent.

Answer (score 0):

<del>The combination I think you are looking for is cmd+right. This will move which ever line you are one one tab in. Cmd+left will move it back one. Your caret can be anywhere on the line.</del>

**Edit**: Obviously far too early in the morning for me. By right I meant ], and left [.